# Where are the error messages of compiling OpenGL shaders in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, glsl

I am using GLSL to write my shaders in and Android application using Android Studio.

Now the shader DOES contain an error. But where can I find the error messages in Android studio?

I am using the example in Android developer guide:

```
    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog`. Example code (with error handling below.) The compilation error message will be spit out to the DDMS logs.

From my experience, you probably won't get a very helpful error as the compilation error message is dependent on the driver implementation.

```
/* Compiles and links the given shader source code */
public static int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    if (program != 0) {
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not link program: "
                    + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
        }
    }
    return program;
}

/* Handles compilation of shader source code */
private static int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader != 0) {
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not compile program: "
                    + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader) + " | " + source);
        }
    }
    return shader;
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but you should not delete the shader before calling `GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)`.

Comment: I agree with kaliatech's comment. I tried the code as included above and glGetShaderInfoLog(shader) returns an empty string. When I changed it to get the log first and THEN delete shader, it finally produced useful error messages. Thanks for the info, it's the first source of real error feedback I've had in my android shader work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to unroll Kaliatech and Daves answer. Because they are right, but it is easy to overread them.

I did get -good- error messages when not deleting the shader. Store stuff in a String. Check the String in the debugger. Do -not- throw an exception. Deleting the shader
or throwing th exception does erase the error message.

```
 public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode, String nicename) {
    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    int[] compiled = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
    String log = "empty";
    if (compiled[0] == 0) {
       // GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);

         log = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader);

        //throw new RuntimeException("Could not compile program: "
        //        + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader) + " | " + nicename);
    }


    return shader;
}
```